# windows server vmware wordpress

Tags: windows

Tengo un servidor fisico comprado e instalado en nuestras oficinas, tengo una ip fija que me brinda mi proveedor de internet, el servidor viene con windows server, tengo instalado vmware y tengo creado una maquina virtual con bitnami que trae wordpress configurado

Me pregunto como puedo hacer para que este sitio web en wordpress se pueda conectar con mi dominio web www.ejemplo.com

alguien me puede ayudar

Comment: Mmm da mas detalles. Dominio web o servidor dns? tu servidor lo tienes en tu casa con ip fija sacado a internet o lo has comprado? en caso de comprarlo, es vps, dedicado...? todos esos detalles nos ayudarán a entender mejor y ayudarte

Comment: Saludos estimado es un servidor fisico lo tenemos en la oficina tenemos comprado un dominio web

Comment: Puedes decir con que servicio lo habeis comprado??

Comment: te refieres al servidor? tiene windows server 2012 el dominio lo compramos con scalahosting

Answer (score 0):

te dejo un tutorial a seguir para configurar las dns de tu dominio:
https://www.scalahosting.com/kb/how-do-i-setup-private-nameservers/

Ahí debes decirle a la configuración de tu dominio que cuando intenten acceder a tudominio.com sea redirigido a tu ip de tu servidor privado xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.

Un saludo

Comment: el wordpress lo tengo instalado en una maquina virtual en vmware 12 pro y tengo una maquina virtual que me descargue de bitnami con wordpress configurado, como deberia de configurar esto?

Comment: Debes poner la ip con la ruta completa, por ejemplo, si desde la oficina accedeis con: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/wordpress/bitnami pues eso es lo que debes poner en tus dns, la ruta que useis para acceder.

Comment: tengo un inconveniente, bitnami me brinda una ip y mi proveedor de internet me brinda otra por eso no me queda claro cual tengo que colocar

Comment: Es fácil de adivinar, prueba ambas desde un ordenador o movil, desde el navegador, y la que funcione y te permita acceder es la que debes colocar

Comment: no funciona ninguna de las dos opciones, creo que esto seria desde windows server 2012 pero no encuentro informacion al respecto

Comment: Has comprobado que tenga el puerto del servidor apache abierto?? Por defecto utiliza el puerto 80, debes mirarlo en la configuración del router.